# Google chrome - disabled auto play

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, video, chromium, autoplay

Since Google chrome 66 the autoplay do not work anymore, how to fix it? 
without setting it manually on every PC's?

chrome://flags/#autoplay-policy
[image]

Comment: `without setting it manually on every PC's` how many PC's do you have so that setting it individually is such an issue?

Comment: Batch1 is in Luxembourg, Batch2 is in Holland, Batch3 is in UK, Batch4 is in Iceland, Batch5 is in Switzerland, Batch6 is in United states, Batch7 is in Australia random locations. All those have Google chrome auto upgrade the application running on those kiosks are connected to a cloud server which has to use auto play. Now many of those kiosks are not allowed to remotely access because of security issues. To modify all those PC's manually will take forever. How to release the fix over the Javascript?

Comment: there is no way to fix it from a webpage - that would defeat the whole purpose. Your kiosks auto update ... do you have some way of deploying changes to the kiosk (that they can get, rather than you needing to connect to them)

Comment: OK - i think it is a manual job then, i have to prepare a new package so that they need to re-install it. In that case, Is there any chrome.exe command line argument to apply this? `chrome://flags/#autoplay-policy ` because when user will install `setup.newversion.exe` how would i apply that autplay-policy settings ?

Comment: https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#autoplay-policy - so, I believe you'll want `--autoplay-policy "no-user-gesture-required"`

Comment: Thank you!!! very much, that would solve my problem, i can release a new : setup.version.exe with that patch on it.

Comment: The `"` are be unrequired - so `--autoplay-policy no-user-gesture-required`

Answer (score 0):

According to chrome from version 66 until now, chrome is update security to prevent any sound from noise to their user. chrome is needed for any action after sound play, if you don't have any action when play sound chrome will be blocked. you can be enabled manually on chrome setting, or you can add this code to your code `$(body).trigger('click');`.